# What could be this mistake? ANSI C file

Tags: c++, c

> [Error] cannot convert 'FILE {aka _iobuf}' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument '1' to 'void relatorio(FILE*)'

```c
case 3:
    relatorio(*arq);
    break;
```

Comment: How is the [c++] tag relevant to this question?

Comment: Well, the answer is in the error message. I can't say how that relates to code I can't see.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory. `relatorio()` expects a `FILE*` pointer, but you are trying to pass it a `FILE` instance instead.  Since you are passing `*arq`, that means `arq` is already a `FILE*` pointer and should be passed as-is, not dereferenced:

```c
case 3:
    relatorio(arq);
    break;
```